# How to produce a fully unique lookup?

Tags: .net, linq

Let's say I have an `IEnumerable` of key/value pairs, that contains duplicates.  If I call `ToLookup` on it and pass lambdas that select the key and the value, I'll end up with a `Lookup` where all the keys are unique, but the lists of values can contain duplicates.  Is there any good way to end up with a `Lookup` where none of the lists of values contain duplicates, in a single LINQ query statement?

I can't call `Distinct` on the original sequence it because the elements are duplicates by value but not by object identity, and `Distinct` doesn't take a lambda for a selector that I could use.

Comment: It's not clear what you're expecting - can you add some sample input that includes duplicates and expect outputs?  Do you have duplicate keys and want unique combinations of keys and values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a GroupBy before building the Lookup in Combination with a select many. This doesnt feel so good however:

Something like this:

```
sequence.GroupBy(kvp => _getKey(kvp))
        .SelectMany(grp => grp.Distinct()
                              .Select(value => new { grp.Key, Value = value}))
        .ToLookUp(grp => grp.Key, grp=> grp.Value);
```

Alternative would be using a Dictionary, since I am not quite sure why you want to use lookup.

```
sequence.GroupBy(kvp => _getKey(kvp))
        .Select(g => new { g.Key, Values = new HashSet<WhatEver>(g)})
        .ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Values);
```

Alternative to Hashset would be providing an [EqualityComparer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/vstudio/ms132151(v=vs.100).aspx) with the Distinct()

```
 public sealed class WhatEverComparer : IEqualityComparer<WhatEver>
 {
    ... implement interface..
 }
```

Then

```
sequence.GroupBy(kvp => _getKey(kvp))
        .Select(g => new { g.Key, Values = g.Distinct(new WhatEvercomparer()).ToArray()})
        .ToDictionary(v => v.Key, v => v.Values);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a little `GroupBy` hack instead of `Distinct`:

```
var lookup = source.GroupBy(i => get_unique_id(i),
    (key, group) => group.First()).ToLookup(i => i.Key, i => i.Value);
```

`GroupBy` will create groups based on the "unique value" you choose. The call to `group.First` will only keep one element of that group. So you remove all others with the same "unique value" or "group criteria". This is basically an extended `Distinct`.

`get_unique_id` should return the same value for the same key/value combination and a different value otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

It seems rather like a trivial exercise if you introduce an anonymous intermediate object.

Try this:

```
var lookup =
    sequence
        .Select(x => new { x.Key, x.Value })
        .Distinct()
        .ToLookup(x => x.Key, x => x.Value);
```

Since you can call `.Distinct()` on anonymous variables then this should work just fine.